# Transform ts class with private readonly fields

Tags: typescript

I have a code similar to this:

```js
class Resolvers {
  constructor(
    private readonly _api: API,
  ) { }

  async products() {
    const { items } = await this._api.getProducts()

    return items
  }
}

function build(resolvers: Resolvers) {
  return {
    Query: {
      async products() {
        return resolvers.products()
      },
    },
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers: build(
    new Resolvers(
      new OZONSellerAPI(),
    ),
  ),
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKBOB7AJgV2AF2gbwFDWmEQDsIN50NF4AKfA6AB3gEsA3MDAU2ni7GQkQAT2gB9FsgBc0Mq2IBzADT0AlDmgBfXPQVcskmurwNe%201PGLQMACxYQAdBOT1tuN6EgwAgrACSBCbQkMLEwNB6GAgolBBGMtEAtvZcADzY0CzciRAy3vDwYMKp0WiYAHxalXj0BHwYFlbEXADucEjJEFw0fBCIIGw8ALzVtQz1jThjpllcOTIA2kGmM9LQAOQAjABMAMzr0wyaALqH2qaaqq7uOrieUNAASlx9A1zwMEFEpOSU1HSmZjsTg8PgCISiMRgRgsPL%20FQEYxaHQEEJhJhIMoYOLGMbfMgaWY5LTQIbBFpgLLWOyOKEwhyRUqxIwo8bmSyZbIQa5uABmqDCGBYJGgACNUCwQMgei9%20oMPjJnq95RBcXV2VZltAAIqod7CGRa1EQULhZgxTA4qYrNkNDm9OXvRzmrE4s4Io4e7RuAD0ACo-fgIDZEKgpWKuPgtbr9YbDmizZjmWqbWY7VYHW8Pg4Xcn3WNNF78H6fXcSATMyrSWKJVKAdBmm0lY6PvWCI3oL4-EYPaoVFcdEA)

How to implement the build function so that it does such transformations “automatically”?

Comment: I don't get why you can't just use `Query: resolvers`.